# How to use Regular Expression to get the dates from this string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<some_text> February 19, 2009 through March 17, 2009 <some_text>
```

How can I pick up the dates using a regular expression, working with python.

I tried this to see if I can at least match the string, but it doesn't find anything:

```
r'\w*\d{1,2},\w+\d{4}\w+through\w+\d{1,2},\w+\d{4}'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be forgetting to match spaces. And you should be using `re.search`, if you're currently using `re.match`.

Comment: I am using re.search(<regex_here>)... Them spaces....

Comment: Doesn't need to be that detailed `(?i)(?#start_date)[a-z]+[ \d,]+(?#through)[a-z]+[ ]+(?#end_date)[a-z]+[ \d,]+`

Comment: @sln That works but it also picks up other stuff, like an address and such.

Comment: Thats the dilema, too relaxed a regex, it matches more than you need, too exact, it will miss aberrant text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
(\w+ \d\d?, \d{4})\b.+?\b(\w+ \d\d?, \d{4})\b
```

Comment: @Drakkainen:In which didn't it work? Could you be more explicit? The first date is in group 1 and second in group 2.

Comment: Yeah if i could learn to copy and paste properly... This work perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use re.search to do this.

Because this will be a long regexp I suggest you compile it, just for clarity.

The basic regexp will look like ths:

```
date_finder = re.compile("(\w+) through (\w+)")
```

This will find two strings separated by 'through'.

To access them you will use

```
out = data_finder.search(input_str)

out.group(1) # first paren match
out.group(2) # second paren match group
```

Next you will have to check to see if your groups are actually date strings or not.

```
date_finder = re.compile("([JFMASOND][a-z]+\s+\d{1,2}[\s,]+\d{4}) through")
```

This is accessed from:

```
out = date_finder.search(input_str)
out.group(1) # date string before through
```

To get the second just repeat that regexp on the other side of 'through'. The regexp might take a little tweaking depending on your input data but you should get the idea.

Hope that helps.